# How to add "My location" option to Place Autocompelete results in android?

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to add "My location" option to auto complete results and add gps icon to most-right part of the search box of the auto complete in order to enter user's location to the box. However I cannot achieve this. There is an Adapter for these I think but I didn't understand this too.

So what I want to implement is this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

What I did so far is just adding the Place autocomplete fragment and onPlaceSelected method.

How can I achieve these? I don't know how to edit the search box.

Better solutions will be more appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: add my location object in zeroth index of searched list

Comment: @Quicklearner actually, I don't know how to do this, I just use the Place Autocomple Fragment. Where is the list?

Comment: alright i got it, wait i will check it

Comment: @Quicklearner are you still cheking it?

Comment: dear i dont see any option with it ,i tried looking for it , i think for your requirement u should implement autoCompleteEdittext with google places api and add 1st object fixed as a home location in it along with the searched results etc

Comment: thank you for your reply